# Why am I getting and invalid QDateTime object?

Tags: qt

My code looks like this

```
std::string date = "04/05/2015 02:07";
std::string format = "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm";

QDateTime dateTime = QDateTime::fromString(date.c_str(), format.c_str());

bool isItValid = dateTime.isValid();
```

This is part of a function I have but I narrowed the problem to specifically that value for date. After executing, `isItValid` is `false`. Why is it not a valid date?

However, if I try

```
bool isItValid = dateTime.date().isValid() && dateTime.time().isValid();
```

the value is true.

Can anyone point out what's the problem with that date? what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentatation of isValid() (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatetime.html#isValid) says:

> Returns true if both the date and the time are valid and they are
>   valid in the current Qt::TimeSpec, otherwise returns false.
>
> If the timeSpec() is Qt::LocalTime or Qt::TimeZone then the date and
>   time are checked to see if they fall in the Standard Time to Daylight
>   Time transition hour, i.e. if the transition is at 2am and the clock
>   goes forward to 3am then the time from 02:00:00 to 02:59:59.999 is
>   considered to be invalid.

So it seems it's the Qt::TimeSpec you are missing.

Comment: I've tried checking the value of `dateTime.timeSpec()` printing it to the console but nothing appears. Also, I don't understand the example, the doc provides, could you help me understanding? Is it that some dates will be always invalid or what?

Comment: For me, both is valid using the code you provided. what is your `timespec()`? Mine is 0, so `Qt::LocalTime`.